# XSLT in OpenJDK 17 gives NullPointerException (Bug in Xalan?)

Tags: java, xslt

I have used XSLT transformation many times in Java thus I am puzzled getting a NullPointerException.

This piece of code works without problem:

```
    Document doc = generateXml(catalog);
    
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(
         "{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(out));
```

Now I want to use a different stylesheet, thus I change the code into that:

```
    Document doc = generateXml(catalog);
    
    URL stylesheet = getClass().getResource("catalog_html.xslt");
    log.debug("stylesheet url: {}", stylesheet);
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
            .newTransformer(new StreamSource(stylesheet.openStream()));
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(out));
```

From the debug log I know that styleheet is not null. Otherwise I would get a NullPointerException when creating the transformer. But instead I get a NullPointerException when executing the transformer, and it looks like this:

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.toCharArray()" because "data" is null
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:792) ~[?:?]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:395) ~[?:?]
    at com.chaudhuri.cataloggenerator.Generator.writeHtml(Generator.java:318) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.chaudhuri.cataloggenerator.Generator.lambda$run$3(Generator.java:248) ~[classes/:?]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762) ~[?:?]
    at com.chaudhuri.cataloggenerator.Generator.run(Generator.java:230) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.chaudhuri.cataloggenerator.GeneratorTest.testRun4(GeneratorTest.java:193) ~[test-classes/:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727) ~[junit-platform-commons-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[?:?]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[?:?]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102) [junit-platform-launcher-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54) [junit-platform-launcher-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114) [junit-platform-launcher-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86) [junit-platform-launcher-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86) [junit-platform-launcher-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.LazyLauncher.execute(LazyLauncher.java:50) [surefire-junit-platform-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.execute(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:184) [surefire-junit-platform-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:148) [surefire-junit-platform-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:122) [surefire-junit-platform-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:385) [surefire-booter-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162) [surefire-booter-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:507) [surefire-booter-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:495) [surefire-booter-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.toCharArray()" because "data" is null
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.getDOM(TransformerImpl.java:603) ~[?:?]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:782) ~[?:?]
    ... 78 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.toCharArray()" because "data" is null
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2SAX.parse(DOM2SAX.java:294) ~[?:?]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2SAX.parse(DOM2SAX.java:275) ~[?:?]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2SAX.parse(DOM2SAX.java:275) ~[?:?]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2SAX.parse(DOM2SAX.java:275) ~[?:?]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2SAX.parse(DOM2SAX.java:192) ~[?:?]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2SAX.parse(DOM2SAX.java:144) ~[?:?]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.dom.XSLTCDTMManager.getDTM(XSLTCDTMManager.java:335) ~[?:?]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.dom.XSLTCDTMManager.getDTM(XSLTCDTMManager.java:214) ~[?:?]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.getDOM(TransformerImpl.java:581) ~[?:?]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:782) ~[?:?]
    ... 78 more
```

While I do not believe this is related to the stylesheet, well here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <!-- TODO customize transformation rules 
         syntax recommendation http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt 
    -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>catalog_html.xsl</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any ideas what could be the cause?

### Edit

Just to see whether the problem was in the StreamSource, I changed my code to

```
    Document doc = generateXml(catalog);
    
    URL stylesheet = getClass().getResource("catalog_html.xslt");
    Document ss = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                                        .newDocumentBuilder()
                                        .parse(stylesheet.openStream());
    Transformer transformer = 
        TransformerFactory.newInstance()
                          .newTransformer(new DOMSource(ss));
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(out));
```

Do I am parsing the stylesheet myself before injecting it as DOM structure into the transformer. This time I get another exception when initializing the transformer:

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Cannot invoke "String.hashCode()" because "this._stringRep" is null
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:1077) ~[?:?]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:834) ~[?:?]
    at com.chaudhuri.cataloggenerator.Generator.writeHtml(Generator.java:319) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.chaudhuri.cataloggenerator.Generator.lambda$run$3(Generator.java:249) ~[classes/:?]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762) ~[?:?]
    at com.chaudhuri.cataloggenerator.Generator.run(Generator.java:231) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.chaudhuri.cataloggenerator.GeneratorTest.testRun4(GeneratorTest.java:193) ~[test-classes/:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727) ~[junit-platform-commons-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.2.jar:5.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[?:?]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[?:?]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102) [junit-platform-launcher-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54) [junit-platform-launcher-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114) [junit-platform-launcher-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86) [junit-platform-launcher-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86) [junit-platform-launcher-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.LazyLauncher.execute(LazyLauncher.java:50) [surefire-junit-platform-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.execute(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:184) [surefire-junit-platform-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:148) [surefire-junit-platform-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:122) [surefire-junit-platform-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:385) [surefire-booter-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162) [surefire-booter-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:507) [surefire-booter-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:495) [surefire-booter-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.hashCode()" because "this._stringRep" is null
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.QName.<init>(QName.java:45) ~[?:?]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Parser.getQName(Parser.java:315) ~[?:?]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Parser.makeInstance(Parser.java:982) ~[?:?]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Parser.startElement(Parser.java:1312) ~[?:?]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2SAX.parse(DOM2SAX.java:269) ~[?:?]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2SAX.parse(DOM2SAX.java:192) ~[?:?]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2SAX.parse(DOM2SAX.java:130) ~[?:?]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:439) ~[?:?]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.XSLTC.compile(XSLTC.java:481) ~[?:?]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.XSLTC.compile(XSLTC.java:575) ~[?:?]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:1036) ~[?:?]
    ... 78 more
```

It seems to be either my stylesheet or Xalan. But even if it were the stylesheet, I'd expect a better message from Xalan than that.

Comment: Seems to be an exception thrown during the transformation when retrieving the source (input) document, here presented as a ```DOMSource```.

Comment: I would check whether it works or fails with Java 8 or 11, too. Then I would check whether it works with the latest Xalan release from Apache or in general, try to run my XSLT with Saxon HE anyway.

Comment: If it were the source (input) document, it should fail the same way using the identity transformation - it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Martin Honnen had the key idea: Simply switch to Saxon HE.
All I did was to add this dependency to my project:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.saxon/Saxon-HE -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
    <artifactId>Saxon-HE</artifactId>
    <version>12.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Now the code runs without a single line changed. The issue must somehow be in the OpenJDK-embedded Xalan version, but it is no longer blocking me.

Answer (score 0):

Since _stringRep depends on the XML namespace (see Xalan sources in JDK17) :

```
public QName(String namespace, String prefix, String localname) {
    _namespace = namespace;
    _prefix    = prefix;
    _localname = localname;

    _stringRep =
        (namespace != null && !namespace.equals(Constants.EMPTYSTRING)) ?
        (namespace + ':' + localname) : localname;

    _hashCode  = _stringRep.hashCode() + 19; // cached for speed
}
```

And since your stylesheet contains some XML namespace (in your case "xsl"), setting isNamespaceAware to true (Kotlin) or doing a setNamespaceAware(true) (Java) on the document builder factory may solve your last problem. It will make the factory generate namespace aware parsers. The default value for namespaceAware is false.

Here is some usefull documentation : https://xalan.apache.org/xalan-j/faq.html#faq-16

Comment: That might fix the secondary problem of parsing the stylesheet. Could you elaborate how you got to this conclusion?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Queeg I edited the answer to be more specific

Comment: While I know what namespace awareness is, I'm afraid I still do not see the connection between this.stringRep and the namespace.

Comment: @Queeg I edited again, hope it'll help

Comment: A much better reference this time, thank you. Now I am thinking where _stringRep might get null. This could only happen if namespace is null or empty and localname is null either. Something that could happen on the default namespace only? Then your conclusion makes sense - given that the stylesheet (or parsed document) always has a namespace defined on all nodes. I am happy to have gone to Saxon...